# Ajax Quicktab with views argument not working

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am facing an issue with the Quicktab Ajax features. I have created four tabs using the quick tab module. Each block is using a view block to show the content using the argument passed within it.

Now the issue is, when i enable the Ajax option "No: Load all tabs on page view" everything seems to be working fine but as soon i changed the option to "Yes: Load only the first tab on page view" only the default tab loads content. Switching the tab will produce no content.

I am using the Quicktab 7.x-3.6 version. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution for this? I'm stuck on this issue now.

Comment: Unfortunately not, so I have changed the code, left this module and make a very own custom module to achieve this feature. However, it is because the requirements changed and the new features introduced which can't be done through the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by enabling AJAX on each view that was being called by QuickTabs. Solution was found here https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs/issues/2903022

Answer (score 1):

Strangely I have sort of the opposite issue with the same version of Quicktabs. I have 2 panels - each with an Openlayers a map in a node on the the left and custom text on the right. If I select "Yes: Load only the first tab", it takes a while but switching tabs does load all the panel content. If I select "No: Load all tabs on page view", the text appears ok but I never see the map - although the read counter does show at the bottom of where the map should be. I'll post again if I can work out what's going on.